# Can an MPI process transfer data and compute on other data at the same time?

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi, openmpi, hpc

Say I have a matrix representing a task I need to compute in parallel on a cluster.
I divide the matrix into submatrices, one for each available process.
But the submatrices are still too large. It takes a non-insignificant amount of time to do the MPI_Send() operation.

So instead my idea is to subdivide the submatrix into smaller chunks. And send the chunks asynchronously, and somehow receive the chunks asynchronously, compute on them and send them back. The idea is that the receiving process would spend less time waiting for the data to arrive and can dedicate that time to computing instead.

Is this possible?
Does this make sense?
What MPI calls would I use on the receiving side to detect that a chunk of data has been received and call a function to compute on that data? I think I can maybe have a loop and MPI_Test() to check for received data and compute on it.

*But primarily I want to know if this makes sense, if it will be more efficient and faster than just a single MPI_Send() call and having the receiving process wait until all data has been received before executing.*

This is assuming the receiving process has no other way to get the data. It is one of the constraints of the system.

Comment: Yes, of course it makes sense. Staying idle while performing IO is a waste of processing time. It's been a while since I've dapped into mpi. But in a local process you can one thread for processing and another for IO (sending the data). Since I haven't played with MPI since my colege years I can't tell you if you can do that with MPI or you need to use threads.

Comment: @bolov Thanks I wanted to be sure about my intuition since I'm new to this. I haven't thought about using threads either. I will look into this myself, but thanks for the idea.